# Laravel database is not found, but i used it before?

Tags: php, laravel, database

Im trying to make a login page for my Laravel project, registration is not a problem, but when i try to login it gave me a error that the Database doesn't excist, the fun thing, the database does excist, because i used it in my homepage. [image: The data is from the same database.]

But when i'm trying to login on the login page, it says: '[2023-02-28 17:48:11] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel''

in the .env is everything correct [image: .env file]

This is my web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ArtistViewController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/inschrijven', function () {
    return view('inschrijven');
});

Route::get('/',[ArtistViewController::class, 'Index']);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

And this is the user model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Ive tried multiple thing, by making a new database, migrate all to it. Nothing is working.

Can someone please help me?

Kind Regards,

Tony

I tried everything, by removing the database, made a new database. I did dd() in the login function by the AuthenticatesUsers.php and it dumps by the first line.

This are the databases
[image: Databases]

After trying multiple things, and using a database connection test to database names 'laravel', is says:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\app> php artisan serve
"Database is connected. Database Name is : laravel" //
app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:24
INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].
Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

Comment: could you login to your sql panel and log your available databases?

Comment: Sure, i added it to the question.

Comment: Where is your Laravel application running? I can only assume that it is connecting to a different MySQL server than the one you're looking at

Comment: Hmm, i use xampp for entering the database server, and i put the laravel project in HTDOCS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, i think my files where corrupted. So it didnt work, i made a new project and it works completly fine!

Thanks for thinking with me :)